# CDK - AWS CodeDeploy does not have the permissions required to assume the role

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy

I have a weird behavior with CDK that I don't understand. I am trying to create a CodeDeploy deployment group with an IAM role. So far, I coded something like that:

```
const codedeployApplication = new codedeploy.ServerApplication (
    this, 
    "CodeDeployApplication", 
    { applicationName: "applicationName" }
);

const codedeployRole = new iam.Role (
    this, 
    "CodeDeployRole", 
    { 
        roleName: "roleName",
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("codedeploy.amazonaws.com"),
        managedPolicies: [ iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole") ],
        inlinePolicies: {
            assumeRolePolicy: new iam.PolicyDocument ({
                statements: [
                    new iam.PolicyStatement (
                        {
                            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                            actions: [ "sts:AssumeRole" ],
                            resources: [ "*" ]
                        }
                    )
                ]
            })
        }
    }
);

        
const deploymentGroup = new codedeploy.ServerDeploymentGroup (
    this, 
    "DeploymentGroup", 
    {
        application: codedeployApplication,
        deploymentGroupName: "codedeploy-dg",
        role: codedeployRole,
        installAgent: true,
        ec2InstanceTags: new codedeploy.InstanceTagSet (
            { "Name": ["EC2_NAME"] }
        ),
        deploymentConfig: codedeploy.ServerDeploymentConfig.ALL_AT_ONCE
    }
);
```

The weird thing is that sometimes I got the error `"AWS CodeDeploy does not have the permissions required to assume the role <ARN_OF_CODEDEPLOY_ROLE>"`. This error does not appear all the time, I noticed most of the time it appears when I do a cdk destroy and then a cdk deploy. However, I checked the role is well deleted at the end of cdk destroy.

Thank you for any pointers

Comment: Please set up aws credentials using `aws configure` and then run your CDK code. you also need to `cdk bootstrap` before `cdk deploy`.

Comment: I already do these steps actually

Comment: This can happen if CodeDeploy runs before CloudFormation created the IAM policy.

Comment: How can I prioritize? I didn't find a way to use the dependsOn method

Comment: First, try without specifying the `role` prop at all.

Comment: Well, if I remove the role line from the ServerDeploymentGroup command it looks like it works all the time. The issue there is that I would like to use my role multiple times (and not create a new one for every deployment group) and I would like to choose a name for it